# French film where the wife/girlfriend changes every morning after sex

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie about 15 plus years ago. It was a French language movie about a man who wakes up with a different wife or girlfriend after he sleeps with her.

The wife/girlfriend doesn't realize that there is anything wrong and treats the man as if everything is normal and they have been together for a long time. The man obviously realize that his wife/girlfriend has changed and is confused, but then he likes the idea of getting a different woman to sleep with every night.

Then one morning he really like the new woman and so doesn't sleep with her. Over a number of days falls in love with her and so has the difficulty of wanting to sleep with her, but knowing if he does, she will disappear and be replaced by a new woman.

I can't remember the start of the movie and why the wife/girlfriend started to get swapped out or the end of the movie, but any clues as to what its called would be great.

Comment: Made me think of "Good Luck Chuck" (not the same movie, but plot similar). Maybe finding a similar movie to it?

Comment: Thanks Larme, but still no joy. I get a bug up my arse every half year or so and go on a hunt for this film, but never get close.

Comment: I remember this. The implication is that he might have suffered a head injury (he mentions a motorcycle accident) and on several occasions he goes to see some sort of doctor (or support group)?

Comment: There's first person POV sex in this. You see the various girls on top of him looking straight into the camera. As he blinks, they change and you see a myriad of topless women one after another...

Comment: I'm sure it was called "unfaithful" or "inconstant" or "infidèle" or something relating to the fact that he felt like he was having affairs with these women

Comment: @Valorum - Is this fantasy? If it's about someone who had a head injury and *thinks* his girlfriend is a different person, then it's not on-topic.

Comment: @Adamant - It's presented as fantasy. If I recall correctly there's only the very subtlest indications as to what's behind it. There's a single line about *a* bike accident much later in the film and we see him attending some sort of support group but you never find out what they're supporting him about. Like all good fillmmaking, you the audience are left to decide what's happening and why

Comment: @Valorum - If he's attending a support group, and it's supposed to be for amnesia, doesn't that mean that he's somehow being apprised of what's going on? How would he be under the impression that this was not because of his amnesia?

Comment: @Adamant - I'm struggling to recall, but I seem to remember that we pick up as he's walking *out* of the support group and talking to a woman who's not his wife. He might even be running the group.

Comment: @Valorum so did you watch that in an English dub? Or if it was the original dub, can you confirm it was French/Canadian French or possibly another Latin language which OP might have mistaken for French?

Comment: @Jenayah - I'm *reasonably* sure that the film was in English but with French actors. It doesn't help that I know enough French that I wouldn't particularly remember if it was in French or English as long as there was dubbing for the big words.

Comment: @Valorum See if the new answer is what you were looking for.

Comment: “getting a different woman to sleep with every night” — _every_ night? Must be French. Once a month would be pushing it.

Answer (score 16):

I think the movie that you (and Valorum) are looking for is [**Poligamy**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1460022/), though it seems you've misremembered a few extraenous details: It's a bit more recent than you thought (2009) and it's Hungarian, not French. From IMDb:

> Andras, the struggling screenwriter one day wakes up to find his girlfriend replaced by a different girl, who acts like nothing happened.

And this *keeps* happening, with him waking up again and again next to different women (that he desires in his everyday life), although it's obvious that it's still his girlfriend - everyone else recognizes her, and she's pregnant with his child. Eventually he also figures out what triggers the change: it happens after he has sex with them.

And it contains the scenes described in the comments: Andras keeps seeing a female shrink to discuss this predicament (and she even *becomes* his girlfriend at some point), and there's a scene with him lying in bed and the women on top of him keep switching.

The movie is [currently available](https://vimeo.com/129528263) online on Vimeo, and here's the trailer:

Comment: Is this actually fantasy then?

Comment: I think so. I don't think the switch is ever adequately explained.

Comment: This is it. Even down to the title.

Comment: Now I need to find out whether I was just imagining the subtle reference to a head injury

Comment: I looked around for evidence of a French dub, but I couldn't find one.  There's a [Spanish-language dub](https://www.amazon.es/Poligamy-DVD-Sándor-Csányi/dp/B00IMGDT8E/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?__mk_es_ES=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&keywords=poligamy+film&qid=1562854937&s=gateway&sr=8-1-fkmr0), though;  is it possible you saw it and misremembered the language?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I probably watched it with subtitles, tbh

Comment: @Valorum Wow, that's very nice of you! Glad I could help. And TBPH, the movie *does* have a French 'feel' to it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Novo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novo) (2002)?

> Those who loved Graham yesterday shouldn't count on today. Those who love him today risk being heartbroken tomorrow... Suffering from recurring memory loss, Graham is restricted to a limited short-term memory. He forgets most things after only a few minutes. He no longer recognizes his wife Isabelle nor his young son Antoine nor his best friend Fred. Since each day is a new day, Graham copes with life by referring to the details of his little notebook, the defining key to his identity. He works as a photocopy clerk under the close watch of his sexy boss Sabine, who uses him to his libido's advantage. Pretty new temp Irene can't help falling for Graham's spontaneous charm. But how can Graham really fall in love with her when he sees each time as the first time? Irene is about to experience all new ways of romance. She'll just have to remember everything for the both of them. Everyone around Graham has their reasons why he should or shouldn't fully recover...

**Warning: Trailer contains NSFW content (underwear + sexual situations)**

Comment: You don't seem to be proposing [Momento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_(film)) as a potential *answer* but rather just a movie recommendation so I've edited it out.

Comment: I don't think this is the movie that OP is describing, assuming we're thinking of the same one...

Comment: Novo is ticking a number of boxes 
- released in 2002 (so around 15 years)
- this is a french movie 
- a man with an injury suffering amnesia
- there's first person POV sex

Note, the movie that I have recommended is Memento (not Momento)

Comment: Unfortunately, we all sometimes make spolling mistakes.